# Questions about the DISPLAY env variable

Tags: bash, shell, x11, portforwarding, nat

Recently, I experienced how to run GUI on WSL2. The key part is to install an X11 server on the host and define an env variable DISPLAY in the WSL2 shell like `export DISPLAY=172.19.224.1:0.0`. Here, the IP `172.19.224.1` is my host's IP in WSL2. And this approach also works in the shell of a VM Linux server.

My Questions are below:

Why the `:0.0`? I feel after colon should be an integer for a port, such as `172.19.224.1:3306` for MySQL. What does `:0.0` mean?

If I use the DISPLAY env variable in the shell of the remote server and the remote server saw my X11 server through a NAT router and port forwarding is in use. What port to forward? (I am trying to use GUI for a remote server, but I find there is a NAT router between and port forwarding is neeeded.)

I do not know the name of the topic and the key words to search. Could someone give me some clues?

Comment: Why do you assume MySQL and X11 would share a format for the contents of environment variables?

Comment: I am so sorry. @Jens, I guess I should do more homework before I ask this question. I am studying the content about X Window System on Wikipedia. I guess this question may represent something that belongs to guys like me, and It may be strange to delete it in the middle, so I do not delete it. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the :0.0?

The format is generally `<ip>:<display number>.<screen number>`.

> What port to forward?

**VNC** uses 5900 + display number.

**X11** uses 6000 + display number.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it later on.

Comment: I am so sorry for the late. I have tried recently, and it works. I forward port 6000 through several NAT routers by autossh and successfully use VcXsrc on Windows 10 to display GUI programs on SSH to server. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `DISPLAY` variable does not contain a port number. The first number is the display number and the second number is the screen number. So `:0.0` means display number 0 and screen number 0. See the [Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367732/what-are-display-and-screen-with-regard-to-0-0) for more information.